# Demazure character (in type A) from Kostant's partition function?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, characters

The Kostka coefficients are the coefficients of Schur expanded in monomial basis,
i.e., $s_\lambda = \sum_\mu K_{\lambda,\mu} m_\mu$.
They are also the coefficients obtained by taking the
complete homogeneous symmetric function and expand into Schur's.
The $K_{\lambda,\mu}$ can be expressed as an alternating
sum involving Kostant's partition function. To be precise,
$$
K_{\lambda,\mu} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} 
(-1)^{\ell(\sigma)} \mathcal{P}\left( \sigma(\lambda + \rho) - (\mu+\rho) \right)
$$
where $\mathcal{P}$ denote [Kostant's partition function](https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/kostkaFoulkes.htm#kostantPartitionFunction).

Now, the key polynomials, also known as Demazure characters,
generalize the Schur polynomials. The key polynomials have several combinatorial models,
but I wonder if there is some analog/generalization of the above identity,
for the key-Kostka coefficients. That is, a similar formula for $K_{\lambda,\omega,\alpha}$
in the monomial expansion of key polynomials:
$$
 \kappa_{\lambda,\omega} = \sum_\alpha K_{\lambda,\omega,\alpha} x^\alpha
$$

EDIT: To clarify, I would be happy if another vector partition function is used, or if the sum is over a different set permutations.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Are you asking for something that necessarily involves the Kostant partition function? For Schurs one hits a dominant monomial with Jacobi's antisymmetrizer (equivalent to Cauchy's quotient of alternants formula). Constant term identities result in the appearance of Kostant partition function. Keys are obtained by hitting such monomials by a sequence of isobaric divided differences. These don't have to correspond to the longest word. So you do not get sums over all permutations. I could say more but need some more clarity in the question.

Comment: @user61318 ok, yes I would be happy if the sum is not over all permutations, or if the partition function is different.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but this is one way to see why classical Kostka numbers involve Kostant partition function. Apply isobaric divided differences starting from a dominant monomial naively, i.e. don't bother simplifying into polynomials the rational functions that result. This gives keys as sums of rational functions with denominators products of appropriate $x_i-x_j$. Laurent expansion and counting the number of ways to obtain a specific monomial then gives key Kostkas as a signed sum of the sort you seek.

Comment: This is not particularly clever. Though I am still scratching my head as far as your motivation for seeking a signed expansion for a quantity known to be positive for several reasons is concerned.

Comment: @user61318 The reason for this is that this type of expressions are used to show certain polynomiality results. For example, the map $k \mapsto K_{k \lambda,k\mu}$ is a polynomial. The only (simple) way I know how to prove this, is via signed expressions involving the Kostant partition function. It would be cool to show a similar property for key polynomials.